# In Javascript, when an element of a large array is used multiple times, is it better to assign it to an other element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to reach a value (direct access) many times in a very large 2D array. Is it better to assign a temporary variable or should I use the array[req.params.position.x][req.params.position.y].anyValue every time?

I know the "new variable" option would make it easier to look at it, I was wondering if that would make an impact on the performance of the code.

My hypothesis is that it acts as some kind of forEach in a forEach and thus takes more time to reach it every time.. ?

Comment: Yes, variable lookup can take less time than indexed property access - but the difference is utterly negligible and not even worth thinking about in 99% of situations. Always write for *readability* first

Answer (score 0):

From your description `array[req.params.position.x][req.params.position.y]`, it sounds like that whilst this is a 2D array, you also know up front the indexes of each array. This is direct access to the array which is extremely quick. It would be different if you needed to search for something in the array, but here you aren't needing that.

Internally, in browsers, this will be constant time access no matter how big the array is. It does not need to "lookup", since the passed indexes will reference the value location in memory -- where it will be retrieved directly.

So there is no performance concern here.